# JSF Material Design Lite

Tags: jsf, material-design-lite

I just tried setting up a simple little example jsf application using material design lite. The xhtml page I created uses parts of one of their basic templates, in this case from mdl-template-dashboard:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://primefaces.org/ui ">
<head>
    <title>Hello JSF 2!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.cyan-light_blue.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
#{welcome.message}
<main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
    <div class="mdl-grid demo-content">
        <div class="demo-charts mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid">
            <svg fill="currentColor" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="demo-chart mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--3-col-desktop">
                <use xlink:href="#piechart" mask="url(#piemask)" />
                <text x="0.5" y="0.5" font-family="Roboto" font-size="0.3" fill="#888" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.1">82<tspan font-size="0.2" dy="-0.07">%</tspan></text>
            </svg>
            <svg fill="currentColor" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="demo-chart mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--3-col-desktop">
                <use xlink:href="#piechart" mask="url(#piemask)" />
                <text x="0.5" y="0.5" font-family="Roboto" font-size="0.3" fill="#888" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.1">82<tspan dy="-0.07" font-size="0.2">%</tspan></text>
            </svg>
            <svg fill="currentColor" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="demo-chart mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--3-col-desktop">
                <use xlink:href="#piechart" mask="url(#piemask)" />
                <text x="0.5" y="0.5" font-family="Roboto" font-size="0.3" fill="#888" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.1">82<tspan dy="-0.07" font-size="0.2">%</tspan></text>
            </svg>
            <svg fill="currentColor" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="demo-chart mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--3-col-desktop">
                <use xlink:href="#piechart" mask="url(#piemask)" />
                <text x="0.5" y="0.5" font-family="Roboto" font-size="0.3" fill="#888" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.1">82<tspan dy="-0.07" font-size="0.2">%</tspan></text>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="demo-graphs mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col">
            <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 500 250" class="demo-graph">
                <use xlink:href="#chart" />
            </svg>
            <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 500 250" class="demo-graph">
                <use xlink:href="#chart" />
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="demo-cards mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--8-col-tablet mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing">
            <div class="demo-updates mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
                <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand mdl-color--teal-300">
                    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Updates</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
                    Non dolore elit adipisicing ea reprehenderit consectetur culpa.
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                    <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="demo-separator mdl-cell--1-col"></div>
            <div class="demo-options mdl-card mdl-color--deep-purple-500 mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--3-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
                <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
                    <h3>View options</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="chkbox1" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" class="mdl-checkbox__input"/>
                                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Click per object</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="chkbox2" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox2" class="mdl-checkbox__input"/>
                                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Views per object</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="chkbox3" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox3" class="mdl-checkbox__input"/>
                                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Objects selected</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="chkbox4" class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox4" class="mdl-checkbox__input"/>
                                <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Objects viewed</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                    <a href="#" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">Change location</a>
                    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                    <i class="material-icons">location_on</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am receiving the error that it can not resolve the main, svg and use tags. How do I get them to be recognized?

Comment: What version of IE are your testing? Do you see any errors in logs or on the browser? i was able to run the above code in my test application.

Comment: I don't see any jsf in here other than the namespaces...  and an EL (not JSF) or is the page a facelets page? Then it should be tagged facelets instead of jsf

Comment: And this code 'just works' for me too in WildFly 10, FireFox 59. No errors at all. Please check different browsers. @Ravi is right... And it certainly is not JSF related. And where is the error generated? Client side? Server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JSF you must use different namespaces for tags such as `head`, `body` and `form`. There are some alternatives that enable them to not be mandatory, but in your case you can just provide the correct names for the main tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://primefaces.org/ui ">
<h:head>
    <title>Hello JSF 2!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.cyan-light_blue.min.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
        //your code here
    </main>
</h:body>
</html>
```

For more examples, you can check this simple quickstart project for JSF: [WildFly Quickstart](https://github.com/BonifacioJose/WildFlyQuickstart/blob/master/WildFlyQuickstart/src/main/webapp/index.xhtml)

Comment: How would this fix the error about main svg and use tags? Using h:head (h:body is less relevant in modern times, often a <body> also works) is only relevant if you use JSF tags that need to load script etc. A plain `<h:outputText>` e.g. does not require it. My suspicion is more towards the doctype.

Comment: And I just tried... Your page does not result in an error, but **_neither_** does the page in the question. It 'just works' for me in wildfly 10, firefox 59